# Class that returns json, python

Tags: python, json

I have a python class that should return a json, it looks something like this:

```
class ScanThis():
    def__init__(self, test):
        data={}
        if test>5:
            data["amount"] = test
            self.json_data = json.dumps(data)
        else:
            data["fail"] = test
            self.json_data = json.dumps(data)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.json_data
```

and I'm trying to call it like so:

```
output= json.loads(ScanThis(8))
print(output["command"])
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'ScanThis'
```

I believe my earlier clas returns an object of type ScanThis() rather than a JSon like I wanted. I just wanted to now how I'd fix this
Thank you

PS: I apologise if this code is rough or invalid, it's not the actual code, just something similar I made up

Update: Again, this isn't the real code, it's just a small basic fragment of the actual code. There's a good reason I'm using a class, and a json is used cause data transfer over the internet is involved

Comment: You don't seem to have grasped the purpose of classes. If you don't want to return an instance of your class, don't use a class - use a function instead.

Comment: `json.loads` does not implicitly call `__str__` on your `ScanThis` instance.

Comment: @deceze right, I honestly just realised how that works from the answer below

Comment: @Rawing I guess not, I've only ever written little python scripts that don't use classes....however a class was required for this one. Thanks

Comment: I should restate, this question is just a super basic lookalike of a section of the actual code, there's a good reason I need a class, trust me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use `str(..)`

You can't **call `json.loads` on a `ScanThis`** object directly. So that won't work. Like the error says, `json.loads` expects a `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray` object.

You can however use `str(..)` to invoke the `__str__(self)` method, and thus obtain the JSON data:

```
output = json.loads(str(ScanThis(8)))
#                   ^ get the __str__ result
```

## Use another method

That being said, it is usually a better idea to define a method, for instance `to_json` to obtain the JSON data, since now you have made `str(..)` return a JSON object. So perhaps a more elegant way to do this is the following:

```
class ScanThis():
    def__init__(self, test):
        data={}
        if test>5:
            data["amount"] = test
            self.json_data = json.dumps(data)
        else:
            data["fail"] = test
            self.json_data = json.dumps(data)

    def to_json(self):
        return self.json_data
```

and call it with:

```
output = json.loads(ScanThis(8).to_json())
```

Now you can still use `__str__` for another purpose. Furthermore by using `to_json` you make it *explicit* that the result will be a JSON string. Using `str` for JSON conversion is of course not forbidden, but `str(..)` as a name, does not provide much guarantees about the format of the result whereas `to_json` (or another similar name) strongly hints that you will obtain JSON data.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me, I didn't really understand the `def __str__` part and honestly thought it got called automatically, really silly of me, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are wanting to use a class there at all.
Instead, try using a function that *returns* a string. For example:

```
def scan_this(test):
    data={}
    if test>5:
        data["amount"] = test
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
    else:
        data["fail"] = test
        json_data = json.dumps(data)

    return json_data

output = json.loads(scan_this(8))
```

However!! Now you are just doing extra work for nothing? Why do you need to serialize a python dictionary as a json formatted string, and then load it back into a python dictionary straight away? While you are working with data in python, it's best to keep it as native data types, and only using the `json` module to either load from a string/file you already have, or serialize to a string/file for storage or transfer (eg sending over the internet).

Comment: I do know using a method would be far easier but the code I posted isn't the whole thing, the full code requires a class. Trust me, I'd prefer a method

Comment: Oh and the actual code does require sending this data over the internet. The part of my question that does the method calling is in a different class

Comment: @DrewU in that case you should have provided more context, including the info you just commented and the reason why you need all the code in the `__init__` method of a class.

Comment: you're right, it seemed to have caused a lot of confusion, my apologies. And thank you